# Javascript if key in array then set it else add to it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been struggling with this for the past day and I can't seem to make it work.  The following code always returns false.  I have tried `hasOwnProperty`, `typeof === 'undefined'`, `typeof == 'undefined'`, I have even tried just using `looped_array[major_minor]['sum_sales']`.  I am never getting the add part of the loop.  It always returns false.

For arguments sake, let's just say I've been tasked to do this in pure javascript.  I can easily do this in PHP and Python, but I can't use them.  Which could very well be my problem, I'm trying to use PHP knowledge and apply it to js.   I am not a javascript programmer, but I need to learn.

I need to loop through several thousand records and build a summed array from them.

My original data looks like

```
item['net_price_extended']
item['pg_major']
item['pg_minor']
```

major_minor is created like so

```
var major_minor = item['pg_major'] + '' + item['pg_minor'];
```

Code I'm trying right now that doesn't work

```
if('sum_sales' in looped_array[major_minor]) {
            console.log("should be true");
            console.log('sum_sales' in looped_array[major_minor]);
            looped_array[major_minor]['sum_sales']            += parseFloat(item['net_price_extended']);
        } else {
            console.log("should be false");
            console.log('sum_sales' in looped_array[major_minor]);
            looped_array[major_minor]['sum_sales']            = parseFloat(item['net_price_extended']);
        }
```

All the code for the loop

```
for(r in margin_array) {
        var item = margin_array[r];
        var major_minor = item['pg_major'] + item['pg_minor'];

        looped_array[major_minor] = {};
        looped_array[major_minor]['pg_major']             = item['pg_major'];
        looped_array[major_minor]['major_description']    = item['major_description'];
        looped_array[major_minor]['pg_minor']             = item['pg_minor'];
        looped_array[major_minor]['minor_description']    = item['minor_description'];

        /************************
         * Calculate the totals *
         ************************/

        if(looped_array[major_minor] && looped_array[major_minor]['sum_sales']) {
            looped_array[major_minor]['sum_sales']            += parseFloat(item['net_price_extended']);
        } else {
            looped_array[major_minor]['sum_sales']            = parseFloat(item['net_price_extended']);
        }
}
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the problem here.  Do you happen to know all the possible fields in the beginning?  You could just set them all to 0 before looping if you did.

Comment: I do know all the fields, but I wanted to do it in one loop instead of using two for performance reasons.

Comment: It would help if you provided a complete code sample that recreated the problem.

Comment: I'm seeing `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'sum_sales' in sum_sales` when I try to run `'sum_sales' in looped_array[major_minor]` in my console -- but `looped_array[major_minor]['sum_sales']===undefined` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration, you overwrite `looped_array[major_minor]` again:

```
looped_array[major_minor] = {};
```

You should do a check to see if `looped_array[major_minor]` has been set, so that you don't overwrite the whole thing:

```
for(r in margin_array) {
        var item = margin_array[r];
        var major_minor = item['pg_major'] + item['pg_minor'];


        /************************
         * Calculate the totals *
         ************************/

        if(looped_array[major_minor]) {
            looped_array[major_minor]['sum_sales']            += parseFloat(item['net_price_extended']);
        } else {
            looped_array[major_minor] = {};
            looped_array[major_minor]['pg_major']             = item['pg_major'];
            looped_array[major_minor]['major_description']    = item['major_description'];
            looped_array[major_minor]['pg_minor']             = item['pg_minor'];
            looped_array[major_minor]['minor_description']    = item['minor_description'];

            looped_array[major_minor]['sum_sales']            = parseFloat(item['net_price_extended']);
        }
}
```